# LIN Network without Transceiver (for testing)

Tags: transceiver, lin

My task is to implement LIN network on SPC560P microcontroller. This microcontroller does not have builtin LIN-transceiver, so it provides TX and RX pins. I know Lin network only has one LIN wire, but I tried to communicate two microcontrollers by connecting their TX and RX pins, like
MC1 TX to MC2 RX
MC1 RX to MC2 TX
But It does not work. I know Transceiver is necessary but I want to try it first just to test that my protocol is working or not.
It that possible to test it without a transceiver? I tried to find revelavent questions but I didn't find it.

Comment: see fig1 here https://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1272421

Comment: You did connect the grounds of the two microcontrollers together, didn't you?

Comment: @Finbarr No I didnt connect them...the grounds together

Comment: Then you should. Unless you use differential lines, the voltages on the TX and RX pins are referenced to ground so it's important that the two ends have a common reference.

Comment: thanks alot @Finbarr. I got it working. The problem was MAX232 and some errors in configuring registers; they were not getting proper values.

Comment: Also @Finbarr It is working without reference ground,  but thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you know that you have any communication working? If communication does not work with direct TX->RX connections, then it will also not work with multiple nodes and LIN transceivers.

You need to get communication running between 2 nodes and add more later.

Connect a USB to UART cable to the RX&TX lines and check the data. If that does not work - connect a logic analyzer to see that your timing/baud makes sense. If that does not work - configure the pin as GPIO and see if it works at all.

Comment: Thanks... I checked some register values, they were not changed at all. Now, I fixed it and its working.